# Visualizing the framing of 3-manifolds induced from a bouding 4-manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, 3-manifolds

Assume $M$ is a closed 3-manifold bounding a 4-dimensional 2-handlebody $X$ which is obtained by surgery on an even link $L$, $i.e.,$ a link whose framings are even integers. Then it's a standard fact that $X$ has a unique spin structure and also a unique framing. Then this framing induces a framing on $M$. I'm wondering how to visualize, or more specifically characterize this induced framing on M. For instance, if we think of $M$ as the union of its link complement and a number of gluing tori, what does this framing look like away from the link and what does it look like in the gluing tori?